# Closing a tab in android

Tags: android-tabhost

I want to implement opening and closing of tabs in android. I can successfully open a tab, but the problem is how to close the tab by simply clicking on the icon of the image on the top of the tab (as with mozilla or IE).

Answer (score 0):

I might not understand your use case correct but I had the use case that I wanted to refresh the tab content when the user 'reselects' a current visible tab. The solution is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5487770/367285). Maybe it fit's for you and instead of refresh the content you can simply close the tab.

Comment: there is an icon and text for each tab when icon is clicked its tab must be closed.now getting here icon is like a cross sign like a browser

Comment: Where is _there_? Do you mean the tab register which you also use to activate a tab? Do you change the icon to the 'cross' when the tab is activated? That means selecting the tab register again should close the tab? Than have a look at my link - or maybe provide a screenshot...