# how to detecting a click on an already selected tab button

Tags: android, android-tabactivity

I am trying to get the Click event when clicking on currently selected tab of my
       TabActivity.

I tried below code but when i click on one tab the other tabs are not working/clicking properly.

```
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "Map");
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "Attacks");
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "Profile");
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "Headquater");

    int numberOfTabs = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();
    for(int t=0; t<numberOfTabs; t++){
    getTabWidget().getChildAt(t).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(TabContext, ""+"i m in on clickkkkk" ,1500).show();
                    getTabHost().setCurrentTab(0);
                }
                if(tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 1){
                    Toast.makeText(TabContext, ""+"i m in on clickkkkk....$#@$#$" ,1500).show();
                    getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

I needed to detect second click only for one tab, so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4349794/1079338) worked for me. The trick is setting the OnClick for the child and not for the TabHost itself.

```
getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Clicked tab : "+getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag());
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);                                    
    }
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly, even for a complex tabhost/fragments setup. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I used theczechsensation solution but with minor modifications because adding a listener to child and not to the tab host itself will cause confusion to tabhost listener to read comments in the code for better classifications

```
 mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // re enforce selecting targeted tab to re apply main listener to default behaviour
                mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
                // display current tab tag in console
                Log.i("MainActivity", "Clicked tab : "+mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
                // identify targeted fragment
                Fragment currentFragment = new "FragmentClassName"();
                // execute navigation (fragment transaction)
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, currentFragment)
                        .commit();
                // re enforce selecting targeted tab to re apply main listener to default behaviour
                mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your ***onCreate*** method:

```
for(int i = 0; i < TOTAL_TAB; i++) {  
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener(this);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setTag(i+"");  
}
```

your ***listener***:
@Override

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()) {
        previousTab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
        currentTab = Integer.parseInt((String)v.getTag());
        if(previousTab == currentTab) {
            if(currentTab == 0){
                Log.i("log", "0th same tab selected");
            }else if(currentTab == 1){
                Log.i("log", "1st same tab selected");
            }else if(currentTab == 2){
                Log.i("log", "2nd same tab selected");
            }else if(currentTab == 3){
                Log.i("log", "3rd same tab selected");
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: and yeah TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();