# Close Tab when it is selected again in android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity, android-tabs

I am learning and implementing the browser for my own knowledge.

I have made tabs and I am able to launch the webpages in tabs.

I want to close a tab when the currently focusing tab is clicked.

has anybody tried to close a particular tab which has current focus ?

I am not using TabActivity and my build target is 9

I am still learning the browser implementation ,so my question can be a little naive so please bear with it :)

I followed a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487770/get-notified-when-current-tab-is-selected-again)

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337514/android-tabwidget-detect-click-on-current-tab?tab=active#tab-top