# Tab bar: on click go to home screen

Tags: android, android-intent, tabbar, multiscreen

I am working with tab bar. I have more then three screens in each tab and when I press the tab button of selected tab, it should go to first screen of that tab, but it doesn't go.
Here is my code for tabar.

```
public class TabUi extends TabActivity {
    private static final String TAG_DEALS = "DEAL";
    private static final String TAG_SEARCH = "SEARCH";
    private static final String TAG_BOOKMARKS = "ALERTS";
    private static final String TAG_FRIENDS = "BUZZ";
    private static final String TAG_MORE = "MORE";
    /*
     * private static final String TAG_DEALS = ""; private static final String
     * TAG_SEARCH = ""; private static final String TAG_BOOKMARKS = ""; private
     * static final String TAG_FRIENDS = ""; private static final String
     * TAG_MORE ="";
     */
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;
    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in
                                                                        // Meters
    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in
                                                                    // Milliseconds

    // private TabHost host = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Resources res = getResources();

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        TabHost.TabSpec spec;

        Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, DealsActivityGroup.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_DEALS)
                .setIndicator(TAG_DEALS, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.deal_icon))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SearchActivityGroup.class);
        spec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec(TAG_SEARCH)
                .setIndicator(TAG_SEARCH,
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.search_icon))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BookmarksActivityGroup.class);
        spec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec(TAG_BOOKMARKS)
                .setIndicator(TAG_BOOKMARKS,
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.bookmark_icon))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, FriendsActivityGroup.class);
        spec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec(TAG_FRIENDS)
                .setIndicator(TAG_FRIENDS,
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.friend_icon))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MoreActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_MORE)
                .setIndicator(TAG_MORE, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.more_icon))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }

    /*@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

    }*/

}
```

This is the code for tab activity group:

```
public class DealsActivityGroup extends ActivityGroup {

    public static DealsActivityGroup group;
    private ArrayList<View> history;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String Url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.history = new ArrayList<View>();
        group = this;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        // new DealsFirst().execute();
        View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(
                "Dealsfirstactivity",
                new Intent(DealsActivityGroup.this, Dealsfirstactivity.class)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                .getDecorView();

        replaceView(view);
    }

    public void replaceView(View v) {
        // Adds the old one to history
        history.add(v);
        v.setFocusable(true);
        v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        v.requestFocus();

        // Changes this Groups View to the new View.
        setContentView(v);
    }

    public void back() {

        System.out.println("History size: " + history.size());
        if (history.size() > 1) {
            history.remove(history.size() - 1);
            View v = history.get(history.size() - 1);
            System.out.println("If size: " + history.size());
            v.setFocusable(true);
            v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            v.requestFocus();
            System.out.println("View : " + v);
            setContentView(v);

        } else
            // System.out.println("History size: "+ history.size());
            this.finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DealsActivityGroup.group.back();
        return;
    }

    public class DealsFirst extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Dealsfirstactivity.this);
            // pDialog.setMessage("Please wait!..");
            // pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            // pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            if (StorageManager.Instance().GetdealscategoryData() == null) {
                ServiceHelper.Instance().Dealscategorylist();
            }
            return null;

        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (StorageManager.Instance().GetdealscategoryData() != null
                    && StorageManager.Instance().GetdealscategoryData().size() > 0) {
                new Dealslistfirst().execute();

            }
        }

    }

        public class Dealslistfirst extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getDialogContext());
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait!..");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                ServiceHelper.Instance().dealsforyoulist(Url);
                return null;

            }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // dismiss the dialog once done
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                if (StorageManager.Instance().GetdealsData() != null
                        && StorageManager.Instance().GetdealsData().size() > 0) {

                    // runOnUiThread(action)

                } else if (StorageManager.Instance().GetdealsData() == null) {

                }
                if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }

                View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(
                        "Dealsfirstactivity",
                        new Intent(DealsActivityGroup.this,
                                Dealsfirstactivity.class)
                                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                        .getDecorView();

                replaceView(view);
            }

        }

        private Context getDialogContext() {
            Context context;
            if (getParent() != null)
                context = getParent();
            else
                context = this;
            return context;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**TabActivity** can indentify when you switch tabs(change from one tab to another) but it cannot identify if you select current tab.

> I am working with tab bar. I have more then three screens in each tab
>   and when I press the tab button of selected tab, it should go to first
>   screen of that tab, but it doesn't go.

For that you need to implement **onTouchListener** in TabActivity.

Please refereed this link for you're issue.
[get notified when current tab is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487770/get-notified-when-current-tab-is-selected-again)

Answer (score 0):

put "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" flag in your root activity intent

```
Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, DealsActivityGroup.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_DEALS)
                .setIndicator(TAG_DEALS, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.deal_icon))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Do same for all your root intents of tabs and after changing tabs you will get first screen of tab by doing this 
and you have to implement tab ontouch listener and put this intent in touch event